# how to set project property to remove warning MSB8004: Intermediate Directory does not end with a trailing slash.

Tags: c++, visual-c++, warnings

I have a vc++ project which has one warning, it is:

> warning MSB8004: Intermediate Directory does not end with a trailing slash.  This build instance will add the slash as it is required to allow proper evaluation of the Intermediate Directory.

After refer other similar questions in stackoverflow, I modify the Intermediate Directory by adding a slash at the end of setting. For details, I did: in project->Property Pages->Configuration Properties->General->Intermediate Directory. Before its value is:

> $(Platform)\$(Configuration)

after modification, its value is:

> $(Platform)\$(Configuration)\

But the problem is warning is still there.
So can somebody tell me how should I fix this warning?

Answer (score 1):

I think the above solution should be correct. The reason it seems didn't work is because I have lots of projects, and it has lots of such MSB8004 warning. I need to fix every project and rebuild all.
Otherwise I believe the warning information in Output dialog is very hard to locate which project these warning related to.

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated from VS2012 or prior, it is because you cannot simply use the same *pch* in multiple projects anymore.
There is an MS page describing how to do it in VS2013+:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/shared-pch-usage-sample-in-visual-studio/